# PHP: Convert Local Time to UTC

Tags: php, datetime, utc

Assume I get a string like `08/22/2015 10:56 PM` and that this date/time string always refers to only one particular time zone. I need to be able to convert that to this format: `'Ymd\THis\Z'`, which is the iCal format.

1. How do I convert that string to Zulu time and into `'Ymd\THis\Z'`
2. How do I then add, say, 30 minutes to that date/time?

Been trying to hack this with strtotime and DateTime, but I'm worried that I'm going about this the wrong way. Maybe there's a simpler and more straightforward solution?

Comment: I don't think there's an "simpler" way than using `DateTime` etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `DateTime`, example bellow:

```
<?php

$datetime = '08/22/2015 10:56 PM';
$tz_from = 'America/New_York';
$tz_to = 'UTC';
$format = 'Ymd\THis\Z';

$dt = new DateTime($datetime, new DateTimeZone($tz_from));
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($tz_to));
echo $dt->format($format) . "\n";

$minutes = 30;
$dt->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes . 'M'));
echo $dt->format($format) . "\n";
```

Comment: And what about adding 30 minutes?

Answer (score -1):

according to subject line; To convert **local time to UTC** you need the timezone name of given local time, or if you have `timezone offset` in GMT; you can try the following:

```
//assume time zone is +3 hours
$offset = 3 * 60 * 60;
$date = date('H:i:s', strtotime("10:56 PM")- $offset);
echo $date;
```

This will output : 19:56:00  which is UTC Time