# IST to UTC timestamp in php

Tags: php, datetime, utc

I have a date time like `30-10-2018 06:00:00 pm`, Now I want to convert it into UTC timestamp, so I am trying to convert this to `strtotime` and multiplying it by 1000. But it leading to 6hrs difference in the resulted date

```
$min_date = "30-10-2018 06:00:00 pm";
$max_date= "30-10-2018 07:00:00 pm";

echo $minDate= strtotime($min_date) * 1000; 
echo "<br>";
echo $maxDate= strtotime($max_date) * 1000;
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider the timezone you're in. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139407/php-convert-local-time-to-utc

Comment: Just two random tips: 1) Relying on a computer being able to tell out American format from European format, when a person cannot, is risky to say the list. I suggest you use unambiguous formats like `2018-10-30` 2) IST seems to stand for "Irish Standard Time", "India Standard Time" and "Israel Standard Time". Geographic time zone names like "Europe/Dublin" are less ambiguous and PHP accepts them out of the box.

Comment: If my answer helped, please consider accepting the answer in order to help future viewers of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to use is a built-in PHP function known as "[gmdate.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)"

Let's use your first timestamp, `$min_date`, in our example of using gmdate to convert the datetime string to a UTC timestamp:

```
$min_date = "30-10-2018 06:00:00 pm";

//Use 'gmdate', which accepts a formatting string and time() values as arguments.
$utc_min_date = gmdate("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($min_date));

echo "<p>Before: ".$min_date."</p>"; 
//Produces: "Before: 30-10-2018 06:00:00 pm"

echo "<p>UTC: ".$utc_min_date."</p>"; 
//Produces: "UTC: 30-10-2018 23:00:00"
```

If you're wanting a purely numerical representation, akin to a [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) stamp, you can simply convert the resulting UTC timestamp.

```
$numerical_utc_min_date = strtotime($utc_min_date);

echo "<p>Numerical UTC timestamp: " . $numerical_utc_min_date . "</p>";
//Produces: "Numerical UTC timestamp: 1540958400"
```