# Converting date to UTC in PHP

Tags: php, timezone

I have this date from my local timezone "2019-07-27T02:00:00"

I'm trying to save it to the database in a UTC timezone, so I can deal with it later and convert to to other timezone from UTC,

But when I do:

```
$date = new \DateTime("2019-07-27T02:00:00");
```

I got a:

```
DateTime @1564192800 {#519
  date: 2019-07-27 02:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
}
```

Whatever I set here,

```
new \DateTime("2019-07-26T06:00:00")
```

I still get a UTC timezone, so this example

```
$date = new \DateTime("2019-07-26T06:00:00");
```

Will get me a result of:

```
DateTime @1564120800 {#519
  date: 2019-07-26 06:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
}
```

It's like the timezone of the date (2019-07-26T06:00:00) is already in UTC? But it's not (?).
So, converting it to UTC with

```
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'))
```

has no affect at all.

Comment: What does your `php.ini` file have set for `timezone`? You can also check with `echo date_default_timezone_get()`

Comment: A good way to do, see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32139407/php-convert-local-time-to-utc/32139499 T

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing datetime as UTC in PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349280/storing-datetime-as-utc-in-php-mysql)

Comment: @Das_Geek , UTC :(

Comment: @Das_Geek, thank you, now I know I have to change it before dealing with the coming date first. if you put your comment somehow as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ahmad Posted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP probably thinks you're *already* in UTC, and accepts any [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) object that doesn't have timezone explicitly listed as UTC as well.

You can check what PHP thinks is your timezone by looking in your `php.ini` file, or by using the command `echo`[`date_default_timezone_get()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php). Similarly, you can edit your timezone globally by editing your `php.ini` file or using [`date_default_timezone_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

[This](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) is a list of timezones PHP can use.

As a side note: though it might seem like a good idea to keep your global timezone set to UTC and just use a `DateTime`/[`DateTimeZone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) to set local variables to the correct offset, don't do it. It'll affect the timestamps of your logs, and can lead to some very painful gotchas.

Comment: There are 2 acceptable occasions to have timestamps in anything other than UTC: 1. User input that you are about to convert to UTC. 2. A formatted string that you are about to put in front of human eyeballs.